# publicar imagenes

Tags: c#, imagen, windows-server

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web https://mispruebas.com en la cual tengo una pagina que sube imágenes a un servidor de tipo Windows Server.

La carpeta donde quiero que se guarden las imágenes esta en la misma que se ubica el proyecto es decir. `C:\Users\adminyo\proyectosdevisual\img....`
La carpeta `adminyo` es la que se me comparte para administrar ya que no es mio el servidor y lo que yo quiero es pegar en ese lugar las imágenes, pero no se como darle el permiso por medio de código C# (es con lo que desarrollo la página) para que me permita guardar archivos ya que cuando guardo me sale

> **Access to the path 'C:\Users\adminyo\proyectosdevisual\img...' is denied.**

Todo esto lo hago de la siguiente forma

```
 string filepath = "C:\\Users\\adminyo\\proyectosdevisual\\img...;
 HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
 Span1.Text = string.Empty;

 for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
 {
     HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

     try
     {
         if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
         {
             Span1.Text += "<u>Imagen #" + (i + 1) + "</u><br>";
             Span1.Text += "Tipo de imagen: " + userPostedFile.ContentType + "<br>";
             Span1.Text += "Tamaño de imagen: " + userPostedFile.ContentLength + "kb<br>";
             Span1.Text += "Nombre de la imagen: " + userPostedFile.FileName + "<br>";

             userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));
             Span1.Text += "Se guardó en: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";
         }
     }
     catch (Exception Ex)
     {
         Span1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
     }
 }
```

La carpeta que tiene los permisos es `adminyo` lo que no quiero es mover los permisos de la misma, mas bien quisiera encontrar una forma de acceder a ella ya que tengo las credenciales, puesto que al entrar al servidor lo hago de forma remota con mis credenciales pero lo que quiero es poder guardar las imágenes por medio de mi aplicación. ¿Cómo poder indicar al servidor que la aplicación esta autorizada para guardar imágenes ?

Answer (score 2):

tienes que darle permiso al `ISS USER` . o en su defecto, impersonalizar el proceso usando tus credenciales, que bueno ese es el camino largo.

**Edicion 1:** Impersonalización a nivel de código:

primero se crea una clase que llama a los métodos nativos de inicio de sesión:

```c#
public class Impersonator: IDisposable
    {
        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
        public WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity { get; set; }
        public IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Impersonator(string userName, string domainName, string password)
        {
            ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(
            IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        private void ImpersonateValidUser(string userName, string domain, string password)
        {
            tempWindowsIdentity = null;
            try
            {
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                    if (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }
            }
        }

        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }
        }
    }
```

Luego en cada fragmento de código ejecutas lo siguente:

Todo lo que este fuera del contexto, se ejecutará con el usuario de servicio, en el caso del IIS con `IIS USER`, y todo lo que esté dentro del `using` se hará con el usuario que indiques en los parámetros `usuario`, `dominio`, `contrasena`

```c#
using (Impersonator imp = new Impersonator(usuario, dominio, contrasena))
{
  MethodoQueGuardaraTuArchivo();
}
```

y eso es todo.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar un poco con lo de impersonalizar. Ya lo estoy investigando pues es algo que desconozco. Si tienes algo que me pudiera orientar seria genial Gracias